# Why do I have 0% coverage on New Code in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, pytest, code-coverage

I created a pull-request in gitlab containing the following python code (in `my_file.py`):

```
def is_significant(displayed_a, conversions_a, displayed_b, conversions_b, tails=1, confidence=95):
    # perform some computation (elided) and return True or False
    return res_as_bool
```

and the following test in `tests/test_my_file.py`, which runs fine using pytest:

```
def test_significant_1():
    assert not is_significant(displayed_a=80000, conversions_a=1600, displayed_b=80000, conversions_b=1693, tails=1, confidence=95)
```

Why does SonarQube mark the line containing `assert` as both *Lines to Cover* and *Uncovered Lines*?

Also, is it related to this warning also raised by SonarQube?

```
Unable to decorate the pull request. Please configure the pull request properties in the project administration.
```